# How to hide transaction source in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is it possible to create verifiable transaction with anonymous (private) transaction source?

I would like to create a system where stakeholders can verify computation, but keep transaction source private. One more condition: user can do a transaction only if he has enough tokens.